# How to combine datasets without looping where one has multiple values?

Tags: r, loops, matrix, dataset

Given the basic tools I know now (which, order, if, %in%, order, etc..), I am running frequently into one problem I call "the uniqueness problem".

The problem basically looks like this...

I have a matrix A I want filled out from another raw matrix, B.

```
 A:  
     [upc]  [day1]    [day2]     ...    day52 
[1]  123     NA       NA                 NA
[2]  456     NA       NA                 NA
[3]  789     NA       NA                 NA
```

B is mega huge row wise, so looping is out of the question.

```
     [upc]    [quantity]          [day] 
[1]  123         11                 1
[2]  123          2                 1
[3]  789          5                 1
[4]  456         10                 1
[5]  789          6                 1
```

I want to fill up day1 for each UPC in matrix A with the quantities in matrix B.  The problem is that there are multiple instances of each UPC in B, and I can't loop over them to get the total quantity to put next to each upc.

So what I WANT is this..  (which would be filled out TOTALLY, i.e. days 2-52 ..by looping over the other days, which is small and thus manageable)

```
A:  
     [upc]  [day1]    [day2]     ...    day52 
[1]  123     13        NA                 NA
[2]  456     10        NA                 NA
[3]  789     11        NA                 NA
```

Do you know any functions that can accomplish this without looping?

Comment: is matrix A empty? ie are you creating matrix A from scratch with unique values of upc and day in matrix B?

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified I have matrix A already.  Both answers were incredible.  Thank you so much for your time and help. I had a really hard time choosing the answer and upvoted both of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a matrix `A` using the `tapply` function:

```
> B <- data.frame(
+   upc=c(123,123,789,456,789,999,999,999),
+   quantity=c(11,2,5,10,6,10,3,3),
+   day=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2)
+ )
> tapply( B$quantity, B[,c('upc','day')], FUN=sum )
     day
upc    1  2
  123 13 NA
  456 10 NA
  789 11 NA
  999 10  6
>
```

If the B matrix is really huge then you might consider saving it as an `ff` object (ff package) then using `ffrowapply` to do it in chunks.

Comment: +1 - I wasn't sure if `B` contained all values for `upc` in `A`, but another option would be `xtabs(quantity ~ upc + day ,data=B)`

Comment: @thelatemail, Yes, your answer is more complete in what the original poster asked for.  Mine is shorter if A does not need to be created first, the `xtabs` is probably the shortest if summing is the method of combining, but `tapply` will be a bit more general if another aggregate is desirec.

Answer (score 5):

If you convert your original matrices to `data.frame`s, you can employ `aggregate`,`merge` and `reshape` to get there:

Make some data including multiple days for the added id of `999`:

```
A <- data.frame(upc=c(123,456,789,999))
B <- data.frame(
  upc=c(123,123,789,456,789,999,999,999),
  quantity=c(11,2,5,10,6,10,3,3),
  day=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2)
)
```

Aggregate the quantities by id and day, then merge and reshape:

```
mrgd <- merge(A,aggregate(quantity ~ upc + day ,data=B, sum),by="upc")
final <- reshape(mrgd,idvar="upc",timevar="day",direction="wide",sep="")
names(final) <- gsub("quantity","day",names(final))
```

Which gives:

```
final
#  upc day1 day2
#1 123   13   NA
#2 456   10   NA
#3 789   11   NA
#4 999   10    6
```